# Can I use my Schengen type C visa with remarks transit to visit my fiancée in Norway?

Tags: schengen, norway, philippines, malta

I'm a Filipino national and seafarer. I will be finishing my contract this January. I've been issued before a Schengen visa from The Netherlands but it's expired. Now I hold a Belgian visa. I already used this visa before I joined the ship in France.

My concern is that after my contract I'm planning to visit my fiancée in Norway. My company will book my ticket for me. Is it possible to use this visa to visit her? She's working there. I'm planning to stay there for a month before going home to the Philippines. I will depart from Malta going to Norway. Thank you.

Comment: Normally a transit visa is not for entering the territory of the Schengen state. I would not risk it. Given your travel history, and the fact that your company is paying for your ticket - you should have no problem applying for a "regular" C visa for Norway.

Comment: Can i have 2 schengen visa in a passport?? Because i ask the company about my visa they told me theres no problem with it because its multiple entry visa.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid but Schengen visas are valid for any legitimate short stay purpose, especially after already having been used for the purpose stated in the application and annotated on the visa.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it was possible.  I'm already in Norway with my fiancee. My Schengen visa is valid for short stay in any Schengen country.  I didn't encounter any border checks other than when I disembarked the ship from Malta.

Comment: Why are people flagging this answer from review?  It's not a "thank you" answer, and, to the extent that it represents additional information, it is additional information that *answers the question.*  In other words, it is a perfectly proper self answer.